# file_get_contents and ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, proxy, file-get-contents

i have php proxy script which uses file_get_contents to get web sites and outputs it ...
everything is working as long as web sites are static, but as long as i use some sites that uses ajax requests to update it's content, lik twitter, 9gag, youtube ... new content doesn't get added
i get this error in console:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://9gag.com/new/json?list=hot&id=6408098. Origin  is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*

since 9gag site is now my local site served by my local proxy it can't access new content from original 9gag site, which this is cross domain issue ....

so my question is how do i take ajax requests and put them through my local proxy server?

Comment: How are you calling your proxy?

Comment: by passing url value in address: mywebsite/proxy.php?url=http://9gag.com

Answer (score 0):

This is a security feature. It is made to prevent such requests that you are trying to do. As I can see, you have only two possibilities:

1. Add site to `hosts` file to forward it to your proxy. It this way you have to ensure that your proxy responds correctly this way. But I don't know if there are some other checks browser-side except checking the domain. If only domain taken into account, everything will be ok.
2. Set OS to use your proxy site as a system proxy. This way you should make it to respond as a regular proxy server.

P.S. May be it is better to use some ready-to-use transparent proxy utility?